# Disable a Script for a Specific Part of a Web Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the top of web page I have a script so links don't work on the page.

```
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.portfolio-featured-image, .portfolio-entry-title').click(function () {
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Is there a way to make one particular link on the page not obey the script? For example make one of the page's many
 `<a href="url">link text</a>` a working clickable link but have all the others obey the script and be non-clickable?

Comment: There's two places you could do it: either change the jQuery selector so that it doesn't include whichever link you don't want disabled, or add some logic into the callback to return something other than `false` if the click was on the live link, which would likely mean evaluating the click event.

Answer (score 1):

add an id to the link you want to exclude from the script like: `id="link"`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.portfolio-featured-image, .portfolio-entry-title').click(function () {
            if($(this).attr('id') == "link") return true;
            else return false;
        });
    });
```